# Get the external contour of multiple small contours in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

So I have the following image composed with multiple and small pieces and would like to get its external contour as follows:

[image]

[image]

I have previously used both *Contour approximation* and *Convex Hull* functions to get the approximated external contours but they were just made of 1 single contour, whereas in this case the smaller parts do matter.

The function I've previously used is similar to this one:

```
canvas = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)

img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/25
img2gray = cv2.filter2D(img2gray,-1,kernel)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img2gray,120,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
im2,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cnt = contours[0]
max_area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

for cont in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cont) > max_area:
        cnt = cont
        max_area = cv2.contourArea(cont)

hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)

cv2.drawContours(canvas, hull, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

As you can guess, the output is far from the desired one:

[image]

Any idea on how to get it closer to the desired one?

Comment: Regarding your desired output (red line), bottom part, a bit left from the center: How should any algorithm know, how to continue the contour here? Why is it not allowed to move further upwards to the small segments? Do you have the original image before binarization? Maybe there's a better solution for the thresholding!? (Keep in mind: That would be another problem, thus a new, separate SO question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Amine was saying morphology operation would be the way to go, especially dilation. More information can be found [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html). Made a small example you can fine tune but I think it's pretty close to the desired output.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cv_img = cv2.imread('spot.jpg', 0)
im_copy = cv_img.copy()

kernel_dilation = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(cv_img, kernel_dilation, iterations=12)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(dilation, 127, 255, 0)

im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cnt = contours[0]
max_area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

for cont in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cont) > max_area:
        cnt = cont
        max_area = cv2.contourArea(cont)

cv2.drawContours(im_copy, [cnt], 0, (255, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow('Contour', im_copy)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can apply morphology operation to close contours, maybe that will work

```
  kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(5,5))
  thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

And then you apply dilate operation to close contours with small gaps

```
  thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel,iterations = 1)
```

Please give me your feedback.